# Simple jQuery Slide Show / Stop on Frame

Tags: jquery

How could I add; or Modify my below jQuery snippet to also just include a stop feature - I'd like the slide show to stop at a specific frame.

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

*Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/camny77/WgRtp/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `clearInterval` like so:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
var i=0; // counter
handle = setInterval(function() { //assign the interval to a variable 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
    i++;
    if (i==3) clearInterval(handle); // stops on the 3rd frame
},  3000);​
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that - http://jsfiddle.net/ykSRU/7/

```
var interval = "";
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
start();

function start() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
  },  3000);
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm going to check these out; take a look at my other question as well - I'm basically trying to do the same thing with CSS3 animation -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810122/css3-animation-keyframe-slide-show-stop-at-frame

Answer (score 0):

I would assign setInterval to a variable, and then using clearInterval on it when a specific condition is met, like after so many slides, or when the src attribute is something you want?